# A line in a proof that $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda^{\kappa})\gt\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

The proof is by contradiction and begins by assuming $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda^{\kappa})\leq\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal and $\lambda\geq 2$.

The line in question follows:

> $\lambda^{\kappa}\lt(\lambda^{\kappa})^{\operatorname{cf}(\lambda^{\kappa})}\leq(\lambda^{\kappa})^{\kappa}=\lambda^{\kappa^{2}}=\lambda^{\kappa}$ giving a contradiction.

My question is:

With the assumption $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda^{\kappa})\leq\kappa$, then does not $(\lambda^{\kappa})^{\operatorname{cf}(\lambda^{\kappa})}=\lambda^{\kappa}$,

making all the terms equal, and thus not give a contradiction?

Thanks

Comment: There is a contradiction, because the first inequality is a strict inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) which tells us that for any infinite cardinal $\mu$: $$\mu<\mu^{\operatorname{cf}(\mu)}.$$

Comment: The point is that once you proved König's theorem, it is a theorem. Even if you assume something towards contradiction, you still can't ignore the theorems that you proved.

Comment: Of course, I cant argue with you, yet, as a naive student doing beginning cardinal arithmetic, with the given conditions, would you not say the second term equals $\lambda^{\kappa}$? So is there a validity to ask which comes first - arithmetic or drawing on a theorem?

Comment: First of all, you can argue with me (as long as we are both open to the option of being wrong). Secondly, you're right that you can make that conclusion. But it will not get you anywhere. Similarly to how assuming that $0=1$ will provide you with a nice proof that $0=2$ as well. You need to use some additional information and obtain a contradiction. In this case König's theorem.

Comment: Sorry to take so long - I had to go out. I remind myself of a line I read in an otherwise forgettable book: There is nothing better to solidify a firm conviction than being wrong.